# BLE + CoreData causes freeze (semaphore_wait_trap)

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, core-bluetooth

I'm developing an app that will receive data through CoreBluetooth (BLE) and store this with CoreData. They work well individually, but not together, and I assume this has something to do with threading.

**What I do**

Im using a singleton to handle the the CoreData interaction. The singleton initialization code is below. The init-code is basically a copy-paste from the Stanford course CS193p.

The first access to the singleton is when the CoreBluetooth receives a certain data block from the Bluetooth peripheral. See code below.

*Singleton initialization*

```
static SessionManager *sharedInstance;

+ (instancetype)sharedSessionManager
{
    NSLog(@"Shared instance requested.");

    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
     });
     return sharedInstance;
}
```

*First SessionManager access*

```
-(void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {
    // First some data processing
    ...
    [[SessionManager sharedSessionManager] addMessageToCurrentSession:message];
}
```

**What happens**

Inside `-(instancetype) init` the whole app freezes (zero CPU, no memory increase) at the line below.
I also added an image of the threads when a breakpoint hit this point (i.e. right before it executes).

```
[self.document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) [self documentIsReady];
    if (!success) NSLog(@"Could not open document %@", [self.documentPath path]);
}];
```

[image]

**My question**

What is going on, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is a bad idea to call an asynchronous method in `init`.  Singleton's are a bad idea anyway.  You should replace your session manager singleton with a normal class and use dependency injection.  You can then remove the asynchronous method from `init`

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Can't I just move the asynchronous from the `init` anyway? For instance, first time I need to access the document, which isn't at `init`. I drew inspiration from here as well, and he/she seems to follow a similar approach. http://themainthread.com/blog/2012/03/core-data-with-a-single-shared-uimanageddocument.html

Comment: Yes, you can use that approach, but you should try and wean yourself off singletons

Comment: Hm, tried, and it didn't help. :/ Off topic: I know there are a lot of discussions about this, but what is _your_ argument for not using singletons? In this case I have a single entity (the database) that I need to interact with from multiple places, but I know to use them carefully.

Comment: The problem you are seeing is a classic case against Singletons - With DI you could trivially inject a null or simulated `SessionManager` in order to test the BT separately from the database functions

Comment: I should perhaps mention that if I use a demo-instance of the CB-interaction (i.e. no actual CB) it works fine. And CB works fine without CD. Off-topic: Thanks for your input on the singleton! Still have the same issue though…

Comment: So it sounds like you need to make sure that your `SessionManager` is fully initialised before you start the bluetooth process

Comment: Perhaps a delegate callback from `SessionManager` once it is fully initialised and use the delegate callback to proceed with the Bluetooth stuff

Comment: I fixed it temporarily by calling SessionManager from the AppDelegate, which seems to have solved the issue. A delegate would be more elegant though. If you summarize your comments to an answer I'll make sure to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a race condition with the initialisation of your `SessionManager` singleton - Your `SessionManager` init calls `openWithCompletionHandler` which completes asynchronously, so `init` returns before the object actually *is* initialised.

I would suggest that you implement a delegate from your `SessionManager` so that it can call back when the initialisation is complete.